# Запрет слияния (мёрджа)

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Можно ли как-то запретить любой мёрдж, если последний пайплайн не прошёл полностью? Речь о Gitlab

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сейчас это выглядит так.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В гитлабе можно запретить слияние, в случае неуспеха, либо в случае, если пайплайн не прошёл полностью. Это делается в настройках

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]